# Creating a row for every second and fifth increment

Tags: javascript, for-loop, modulo

I have a grid and would like to create a row for every second and fifth increment in my for-loop. It would look something like 2,3,2,3...If I had, say 18 increments how could I achieve this? I tried using `i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0` in the loop but get a variable result. Math isn't really my strong suit so help would greatly be appreciated

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement('div');
  span.classList.add('span');

  if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add('row');
    frag.appendChild(row)
  }

  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    span.classList.add('span8')
  } else {
    span.classList.add('span4');
  }

  row.appendChild(span);
}

container.appendChild(frag)
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100px;
}

.span8 {
  flex: 1;
}

.span4 {
  flex: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: *"every second and fifth"* doesn't go with *`i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0`* - do you want every second or every third?

Comment: Your modulus for "every second increment" fires on all even elements, so that's not going to work.  I'll post an answer with a counter check that swaps on successive rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... It loses your mod calculations.  The way you originally described it it, it would have run on every even instance (although your code had a 3 instead of a 2).  Plus, the loop started on a zero count, so that would have been an issue as well.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var colset = 2;
var colcounter = 0;
var row = document.createElement('div');
row.classList.add('row');

for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  colcounter++;
  var span = document.createElement('div');
  span.classList.add('span');
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
     span.classList.add('span8');
  } else {
     span.classList.add('span4');
  }
  span.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', i);
  row.appendChild(span);
  if ( colcounter === colset ) {
    frag.appendChild(row);
    colcounter = 0;
    colset = ( (colset === 3) ? 2 : 3 );
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add('row');
  }
}
if ( colcounter > 0 ) {
  frag.appendChild(row);
}
container.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100px;
}

.span8 {
  flex: 1;
}

.span4 {
  flex: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a few questions. What's the purpose of the last conditional and why does it exist **outside** the loop? Originally I had set a `span8` class to the first span in every odd row to fit my current bootstrap grid. Can I still accomplish this with your code above?

Comment: The purpose of the last conditional is to catch any stray spans that are left in the row but weren't posted to `frag` yet. It's outside the loop because the element generation loop is complete.  If the counter is greater than zero, additional spans are still waiting to be placed in frag. Also, I actually saw an error in my code (hard to believe :P ) and fixed it.

Comment: `if ( colcounter < colset )` instead of `if ( colcounter > 0 )`. I added your `span` formatting back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider of creating a counter variable,which starts with 1 and increment on every iteration,if it 2 or 5 run your logic and once counter becomes reset it back to 1 and run the same logic

check this snippet

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var count = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {

  var span = document.createElement('div');
  span.classList.add('span');

  if (count == 2 || count == 5) {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add('row');
    frag.appendChild(row);


    if (count == 5) {
      span.classList.add('span8');
      count = 1;
    } else if (count == 2) {
      span.classList.add('span4');
    }
    row.append(span);
  }
  count++;


}

container.append(frag);
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100px;
}
.span8 {
  flex: 1;
}
.span4 {
  flex: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Hope it helps